# How to open a file in C without losing its previous contents?

Tags: c, file, file-io

If the file doesn't exist I want to create it. But the next time that the program runs I want to open the file without losing its previous contents. Can anyone help? I have one function that loads the file and another that saves the file. I just don't know what mode I should use

Comment: try to open for reading, if that fails try to open for writing, basically: `if (fopen(fname, "r+") == NULL) fopen(fname, "w+")`

Comment: Opening the file in append-mode might be the simplest solution (because it creates the file if it doesn't exist), but of course that only makes sense if you don't actually want to read the contents, but just add stuff to the end. (or you do a `rewind()` after opening)

Answer (score 1):

You can update the already existing text with a call to `fopen` using append mode, so to update this previously created file without erasing the data you can use the mode `"a"` like this:

```
ptr = fopen("file_name.txt","a") //(a=append)
```

This will add your `fprintf`ed strings or other inputted data at the end of the `.txt` file, instead of overwriting from the beginning